# Get List of 1st and 3rd Saturday of month if 2nd Saturday Appear in first 9 days

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I want to get List of all 2nd & 4th Saturdays of an year. But if 2nd Saturday appear in first 9 days of a month then return list of 3rd and 5th Saturday of that month. So far i get list of all 2nd & 4th Saturday of whole year. But I'm not able to get 3rd and 5th Saturday if 2nd Saturday appear in first 9 days of a month.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DateTime> MyCalendar = new List<DateTime>(); //create list
        DateTime currDate = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1); //initial value
        //add days to MyCalendar
        while (currDate <= new DateTime(2017, 12, 31))
        {
            MyCalendar.Add(currDate);
            currDate = currDate.AddDays(1);
        }
        //method to get 2. and 4. saturday in month
        var result = MyCalendar.Where(x => x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Month)
                        .SelectMany(grp =>
                            grp.Select((d, counter) => new
                            {
                                Month = grp.Key,
                                PosInMonth = counter + 1,
                                Day = d
                            }))

                        .Where(x => x.PosInMonth == 2 || x.PosInMonth == 4)
                        .ToList();

        foreach (var d in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", d.Month, d.PosInMonth, d.Day);
        }

        Console.Read();

    }

}
```

Out Put of the Program

[Out of Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35iJk.png)

Comment: By extrapolation, if the 2nd Saturday occurs within the first 9 days of the month, the 1st Saturday must occur on the 1st or 2nd of the month, otherwise you push the 2nd Saturday out of the 9-day window. So basically just calculate the 1st and 3rd Saturday as normal, and if the "day of the month" of the 1st Saturday is 1 or 2, move both Saturdays out one week.

Comment: What are your expected results for December 2016?

Comment: @IvanStoev This very month (October) has 5 saturdays...

Comment: @MatthewWatson LOL, how stupid am I :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson But seriously, looks like your assumption for *last saturday of each month and the saturday two weeks before that* is the real intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty solution; I admit that it could be more optimized.

Method which will do the lookup:

```
private static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetWeekDayOfMonth(DateTime monthToCheck, DayOfWeek weekDayToFind)
{
    var year = monthToCheck.Year;
    var month = monthToCheck.Month;
    var dayCount = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
    var daysList = Enumerable.Range(1, dayCount)
                                    .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day))
                                    .Where(date => date.DayOfWeek == weekDayToFind)
                                    .ToList<DateTime>();
    // Loop with 2 increment
    int lookupStart = 1;
    int loopCount = 0;
    if (daysList[1].Day <= 9)
    {
        lookupStart = 2;
    }

    for (var i = lookupStart; i < daysList.Count(); i = i + 2) 
    {
        if (loopCount < 2)
        {
            yield return daysList[i];
            loopCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code to call it:

```
private static void FindWeekDays()
{
    DateTime dateToCheck = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);
    List<DateTime> dayList = new List<DateTime>();
    while (dateToCheck.Year <= 2017)
    {
        dayList.AddRange(GetWeekDayOfMonth(dateToCheck, DayOfWeek.Saturday));
        dateToCheck = dateToCheck.AddMonths(1);
    }

    dayList.ForEach(date => Console.WriteLine(date.ToString()));
}
```

And the Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FindWeekDays();
}
```

Comment: Will i try the same program for sundays of whole year with same statement

Comment: With same statement as i mentioned in the above Statement

Comment: You just need to change the statement `dayList.AddRange(GetWeekDayOfMonth(dateToCheck, DayOfWeek.Sunday));` to do lookup for `Sunday`

Comment: Ok Thanks You so much. I've another Problem regarding same statement. can i ask you

Comment: See the above is practically correct; but logically there can be more optimal solution. What is your question?

Comment: Let me ask you one thing first

Comment: I want my Solution in this Format

Saturday, January , 14 2017

Comment: Again quick and dirty - `Console.WriteLine(date.DayOfWeek + date.ToString(", MMMM, dd yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")))` or just `Console.WriteLine(date.DayOfWeek + date.ToString(", MMMM, dd yyyy"))` without culture information

Answer (score 1):

Another method

```
            DateTime currDate = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1); //initial value
            int dayOfWeek = (int)currDate.DayOfWeek;
            currDate = currDate.AddDays(6 - dayOfWeek);
            //add days to MyCalendar
            while (currDate <= new DateTime(2017, 12, 31))
            {
                MyCalendar.Add(currDate);
                currDate = currDate.AddDays(7);
            }
            var result = MyCalendar.GroupBy(x => x.Month).Select(x => x.Skip(1).First().Day <= 9 ? new DateTime[] { x.Skip(2).First(), x.Skip(4).First() } : new DateTime[] { x.Skip(1).First(), x.Skip(3).First() }).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

            foreach (var d in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", d.Month, d.Day);
            }

            Console.Read();
```

Comment: Your Solution returning all sundays list not saturday list

Comment: Fixed,  Got my variables mixed up.

Comment: Thanks, Its Working fine now

Comment: It is returning a List<DateTime>.  Not a formatted string.  Just like your original code.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            foreach (var saturday in FilteredSaturdays(DateTime.Now, new DateTime(2017, 12, 31)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(saturday);
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<DateTime> FilteredSaturdays(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            DateTime startMonth = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, 1);
            DateTime endMonth = new DateTime(end.Year, end.Month, 1).AddMonths(1);

            for (DateTime month = startMonth; month < endMonth; month = month.AddMonths(1))
            {
                // Work out date of last saturday in the month.

                DateTime lastDayOfMonth = month.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
                DateTime lastSaturdayOfMonth = lastDayOfMonth.AddDays(-(((int)lastDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek+1)%7));

                // Return saturday 2 weeks before last saturday of month, and last saturday of month.

                yield return lastSaturdayOfMonth.AddDays(-14);
                yield return lastSaturdayOfMonth;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is going to be more efficient than looking at every single day of the year to see if it's a Saturday!

[EDIT] It seems that the actual requirement is that you want the last Saturday in every month and the Saturday two weeks before that Saturday, so I have updated my solution accordingly.

Comment: Only before the 3rd, not on the 3rd, if the 1st Saturday is on the 3rd of the month, the 2nd Saturday will be on the 10th of the month.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Hmm yes, but now thinking about it does the OP really want the last saturday of each month and the saturday two weeks before that? I'll ask in a comment to the OP.

Comment: Your Solution Provides good results. But i need solution in LINQ. Thanks to you

Comment: I want Saturday on 17 & 31 for December 2016

Comment: @ShahbazCheema In that case your requirement is wrong! You say `if 2nd Saturday appear in first 9 days of a month then return list of 3rd and 5th Saturday of that month` but December 2016 has a second saturday on the 10th, yet you still want to return the 3rd and 5th saturdays.

Comment: @ShahbazCheema Why do you need a solution in Linq? Don't you just need to get a list of all the saturdays?

Comment: I agree with You. Can you provide solution in linq?

Comment: This Solution is Working fine

Comment: @ShahbazCheema I'm not sure this is correct because it returns 10th and 24th for December 2016. I'll post an alternative version in a bit.